# Expire token 401 in partner center API

Tags: curl, azureportal, guzzle

I tried to log into Microsoft partner center using api –via postman

(https://login.microsoftonline.com/******/oauth2/token)

, Of course after following the steps that Microsoft placed regard Partner Center API calling which are:

•   Register your app with Azure AD.

•   Get authorization.

•   Get an access token.

•   Call Microsoft Graph with the access token.

•   Use a refresh token to get a new access token.

It worked perfectly on Postman. It did login and retrieved all available customers in my partner center account. The api I used was:

https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers

However, when I tried to run it locally in my Laravel project, I was able to sign into my partner center account and return token but kept facing “401 unauthorized access” whenever I try to retrieve all available customers. The thing is, I even fixed my token yet received the same error message.

I tried this scenario with 2 different libraries (GuzzleHttp\Client) and CURL, yet received the same error message.

Why would it work on Postman but not locally? Is there something I have to add to my project?

I googled a lot but couldn’t find the answer or anything slightly related to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @FesalAli, have you had any luck resolving the issue, I am currently having the exact same issue